# Where to find "MIP Emphasis" parameter in the CPLEX IDE?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, solver

I am also looking to solve a MIP with heuristic algorithms and read in the guide that I need to modify the "MIP emphasis" parameter. Is there a way of doing this in the CPLEX IDE? All I can find is "Effort level of heuristics" in the settings menus. Or do I need to move to python/C++ to modify this setting?

Answer (score 5):

You can do that in scripting:

```
execute
{
  cplex.mipemphasis=3;
}
```

or in the IDE

[image]